# How to create slider for Upsell product and keep related items in simple grid view?

Tags: magento2, slider

I am running a store on Magento 2 and on **product page** I **want to show upsell products in slider** while keeping the **related items in simple grid view.**

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of this free extension https://www.weltpixel.com/owl-carousel-and-slider.html

You can create banner slider for Homepage and product sliders for any page

You can create slider for following types :

```
New Products
Best Sell Products
Sell Products
Recently Viewed Products
Related Products
Upsell Products
Cross-sell Products
```

For displaying  upsell items in slider , keep **upsell products** option to **enable** , so they will display in slider. **Keep other options disabled for displaying them in simple grid view**

For any issue with configuration , let me know

Thanks